# 2D array: 1 dimension determined at run time, other known at compile time

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

A method named `generateRandomArray(int minLength, int maxLength, int minVal, intMaxVal)` returns a random array of random length. I want 1 random array generated and then have it copped 5 times. I plan on doing mostly the same manipulations to the array so I want to be able to use a loop on an array of these arrays. So I want a 2D array, where 1 dimension is the length of the randomly generated array returned and the other dimension is 6. How do I do this? `int[][6] test = generateRandomArray(3,50,-100,100)[];` gives `] expected`.

Right now I have

```
    int[] a1 = generateRandomArray(minLength, maxLength, minVal, maxVal);
    int[] a2 = a1.clone();
    int[] a3 = a2.clone();
    int[] a4 = a3.clone();
    int[] a5 = a4.clone();
    int[] a6 = a5.clone();
    a1.doWork();
    a2.doWork();
    a3.doWork();
    //...
    a1.callMethodX();
    a2.callMethodY();
    a3.callMethodZ();
    //...
    System.out.println(Array.toString(a1));
    System.out.println(Array.toString(a2));
    System.out.println(Array.toString(a3));
    System.out.println(Array.toString(a4));
    System.out.println(Array.toString(a5));
    System.out.println(Array.toString(a6));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this:

```
int[] a1 = generateRandomArray(minLength, maxLength, minVal, maxVal);
int a[][] = new int[6][];
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = a1.clone();
}
```

You create an array that can hold 6 arrays. Then you use a loop to place the 6 copies of the random array into this array.

```
// Using it:
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    a[i].doWork();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a[i]));
}
```

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong, I had the constant on the wrong side of the equals in `int a[][] = new int[6][];` How did you know it was this and not `int a[6][] = ...`?

Comment: do you understand my question? Why did you put the literal on the right of the equal sign instead of the left for the array? If you don't answer I'll ask the question by itself on SO.

Comment: @Celeritas I'm not sure whether I understood the question, and whether it is answered in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html . In general, the *declaration* does not contain the array size. So it's not `int a[6][];´ but always only `int a[][];`. Only when you assign a value, you either say `int a[][] = new int[6][];` (defining only the size along the first dimension), or `int a[][] = new int[6][123];` (do define the whole array size).